# shared library apparently not containing any routines

Tags: r, shared-libraries, rcpp

I'm trying to make an R interface to the [C++ library Faddeeva](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Faddeeva_Package) (various types of complex error functions); unfortunately I have very little experience in calling external code in R and it's proving quite a challenge.

My naive attempt,

```
R CMD SHLIB Faddeeva.cc
```

produced a shared library `Faddeeva.so`, which I load in R,

```
dyn.load("Faddeeva.so")
dlls <- getLoadedDLLs()
getDLLRegisteredRoutines(dlls[['Faddeeva']])
```

It's empty, I haven't registered any of the functions. I believe I'll have to write some interface code to work with SEXPs so that I can use the .Call interface (could Rcpp make this step easier?), but I'm still confused as to why this shared library shows no registered routines.

Any advice or directions for undertaking such a project will be most welcome!

---

Edit: Thanks to Dirk's answer and help with Rcpp, the interface is now implemented in the [Faddeeva package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppFaddeeva/index.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would step back and look at other packages which use external libraries.  The oldie but goldie is [RcppGSL](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.gsl.html), but for example [RcppRedis](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=RcppRedis) using the (C-library) [hiredis](https://github.com/redis/hiredis).

There is really no deep magic:

1. Use a header file from the other library to declare identifiers
2. Write a short C++ file to deploy one of those identifiers
3. Link against the other library (which ought to be visible on your system--on Linux do `ldconfig -p | grep libraryname`) by adding it in `src/Makevars` to `PKG_LIBS`.
4. Alternatively, if you shib the sources of Johnson's Fadeeva in your package, just include the files in `src/` and skip step 3.

Note that I have said nothing about [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html). It "only" helps with point 2. The rest is the same as linking a C library to an R extensions.  Which probably a thousand different packages on CRAN do.

If you are completely lost, consider [the new list r-package-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-package-devel) but do read a little in [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) first.

Jelmer's package [nloptr](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=nloptr) wraps another of Johnson's libraries: [nlopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt). Maybe that can help as inspiration. I helped a little making the installation more efficient (by using a system `libnlopt` where present).

*Edit:* I had a closer look at the [page by Johnson](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Faddeeva_Package).  There is no library.  Just a `.cc` and `.hh`.  Drop those into `src/` of your package, possibly renameding to `.cpp` and `.h` -- and you are done!

*Edit 2:*  Ok, I created a little sample package per the recipe I just outlined.  By using [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) the caller becomes as simple as

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

#include "Faddeeva.h"

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double Dawson(double x) { // special case for real x
  return Faddeeva::Dawson(x);
}
```

and we can use the package as usual:

```
edd@max:/tmp$ Rscript -e 'library(RcppFaddeeva); Dawson(4.2)'
[1] 0.122761
edd@max:/tmp$
```

I'll put this on GitHub in a moment.

*Edit 3:* It is now [in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppfaddeeva).

Comment: thanks for the tips. I'm trying to get a feel for how much work #2 would involve (unfortunately, I cannot afford to spend much time figuring it out, when I can call it with the Matlab interface and get the job done...). I've linked to simple bits of external code before, following R-exts examples, but this is a much more daunting task (partly because the original code structure is way over my head). I looked at various R packages, but so far I haven't found a minimal example bearing close resemblance (no c++ templates, yet hopefully making use of Attributes to minimise the wrapping code.)

Comment: You really are overcomplicating this!  Two cases: a system library (think `libpng`--see `RcppGSL`) or included with your package (see many others like eg `nlopt`).

Comment: See my edit. There is nothing to do here.  Include the `.cc` as `.cpp`; R will then compile and link.  Call one of the identifiers from the `.hh` (renamed as `.h`).  End of story.

Comment: `getDLLRegisteredRoutines()` still gives me an empty data.frame, whether I load manually, or via a dummy package. The compilation step doesn't return any error, but there's probably something in the source masking the routines from R.

Comment: because how else would I check whether there's anything at all I can call? I tried to call the various routines listed in the header file, with `.Call()` and `.C()`, and they don't appear to exist `"Error in .C("erfcx") : C symbol name "erfcx" not in load table"`. [Link to a dummy package](https://github.com/baptiste/faddeeva). Time for me to take a break and come back to this later.

Comment: See my third edit -- there is now a working (albeit minimal) package on GitHub.

Comment: Wow. Many thanks for this is a fantastic walk-through example.

Comment: You're welcome.  It really wasn't that hard. We could expand the little package together if you want.  There were also other notes on his page -- did you ever see [libcerf](http://apps.jcns.fz-juelich.de/doku/sc/libcerf)?  Anyway, we now have a working self-contained piece to work from.

Comment: It would be great to release it at some point, yes. I'll work on improving the coverage, add a few tests, and contact Steve Johnson when it looks reasonably ready. I haven't looked closely at libcerf, it's probably not all that different so we might as well stick with the original source.